# remmina desktop client not working properly,shows login failed

Tags: 15.04, remote-desktop, remmina

I have used a desktop client in windows and it works fine. 
I could not find what the problem is.
Simply shows login failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following methods

> ssh user@domain

from the terminal

or

> sftp://user@dommain/home/

and try to connect the server

This will verify the login, if it works then your desktop client must also work.

I these attempts fail,then it simply means that your password is wrong ,contact your admin to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my previous encounters with this problem, I do the following and my problem was solved:

1. I deleted the entry from `~/.freerdp/known_hosts` (or somewhere else that your remmina config is stored.)
2. Click Advanced tab in my Remote Desktop Preferences and choose RDP in Security drop down menu and save.

Hope this help you